# Setting up DKIM Private Key? Where do I put it? Details inside

Tags: dns, rsa, private-key, dkim

I have been searching for hours for this answer and don't have much experience recently with DKIM.

I've updated my host(HostMonster) DNS TXT records with the DKIM public key information as follows:

`default._domainkey.domain.com = k=rsa;p=key`

`verify._domainkey.domain.com = k=rsa;p=key`

`_domainkey = k=rsa;p=key`

But I'm not sure where to put the private DKIM key?

My client is using Thunderbird to send mails from their machine and from there it goes directly to HostMonster hosted email, then out to their federal client who enforces DKIM signing and rejects unsigned messages.

After hours of searching on Google, I've yet to find where to put that private key! There's nowhere in thunderbird to put it, and one DNS "expert" said to put it as a TXT record in the DNS with the private key as the DNS value of that record, but I was under the assumption that would make the record public and expose the private key?

Thank you for your help in this matter! I've been pulling my hair out over this one and my client is dead in the water being unable to send signed messages to conduct business! My apologies if this isn't posted in the correct forum!

Comment: This forum is for programming questions - not system admin.  Saying that, your DKIM private key is configured on the sending mail server.  Your Thunderbird client doesn't need it as it signs in with credentials.  The sending mail server uses it to prove that it's authorised to send for the domain.  Receiving email servers can look up the public key in DNS and confirm the sending domain has the private key and is therefore authorised to send.

Comment: Thank you and my apologies.